# Permission error, pip install

Tags: python, permissions, pip, fedora

I just started with a new build of fedora, and I am trying to pip install pew, so that I can work on some virtual python environments.

The pip install went correctly, at least I think so.

```
>>> pip -V
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I know the version is a bit outdated, but I have pip at least. Now when I try and grab pew, this happens.

```
>>> pip install pew
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pew
  Using cached pew-0.1.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pythonz-bd>=1.10.2 (from pew)
  Using cached pythonz_bd-1.11.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting shutilwhich (from pew)
  Using cached shutilwhich-1.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=17.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pew)
Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (from pew)
  Using cached backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 (from pew)
  Using cached virtualenv-clone-0.2.6.tar.gz
Collecting pathlib (from pew)
  Using cached pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting virtualenv>=1.11 (from pew)
  Using cached virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pythonz-bd, shutilwhich, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, virtualenv-clone, pathlib, virtualenv, pew
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 308, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 816, in install
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1013, in move_wheel_files
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 70, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pythonz_bd-1.11.2.dist-info'
```

Seems to me, based solely on the "Permission denied" bit, I should do something like this.

```
sudo pip install pew
```

After asking me for a password, I get this message over and over.

```
Collecting pew
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/pew/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/pew/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/pew/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/pew/

etc...
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to pip install correctly on my new fedora build?

Comment: I seemed to get around this issue by changing to root "sudo su -" and then pip installing pew, but I won't answer until I figure out why and how this worked.

Comment: I tried to install on Ubuntu and it works. It seems you are facing network issue. Please check you network ( using ping command) and your proxy (if any)

Comment: Not directly related, but instead of using sudo pip, try setting up a virtualenv and install your libraries within it (may be using requirements.txt). It will be portable.

Comment: @Vivek what url should I try and ping?

Comment: @Vivek, I attempted  to ping google.com, that got me an "unknown host" message. I think I have got my proxies set in the global bashrc though, because I was able to use wget without issue.

Comment: It appears that I am able to ping other computers on my network though, so the problem must be a proxy issue I am thinking? The thing is, I have both exported my proxies as well as sourced them in /etc/bashrc

Comment: env | grep -i "proxy" 
and I see they are set.

Comment: @Thrustmaster (lol at username), is this a similar thing to pew? That is ultimately what I want to get going.

Comment: @Zack "Unknown host" is because either you internet not working or your DNS is not resolving.

Comment: @Zack: (That handle has stuck with me for a long time, dont even remember origin), You're right. I didn't know about pew. Pew seems to be a manager of multiple virtualenvs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot I had even asked this, but I needed to "sudo su" because I was trying to install the python packages to somewhere requiring root.

The more permanent fix was to use [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew) to manage my python environments. In the context of a pew environment, I installed the python packages to somewhere not requiring root, and the problem went away.